# python install numpy and matplotlib exceptions (using pip)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pip

I encountered the following error as I was installing the numpy and matplotlib. I don't know how to fix it.

```
    D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python36-32>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/matplotlib/
  Downloading matplotlib-2.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl (8.7MB)
    14% |████▌                           | 1.2MB 33kB/s eta 0:03:46Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 232, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "d:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 314, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "d:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 60, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "d:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 449, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "d:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 493, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "d:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "d:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1002, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "d:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 865, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "d:\program files (x86)\python\python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 625, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

I'm new to python, how can I fix it?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just download the whl binary

Comment: and check your internet speed, 33kB/s aren't much..

Comment: Seems like the internet connection timed out during the download. Did you retry after some minutes? Does it always stop at 14%? Is your internet working fine otherwise?

Comment: Problem fixed after I download get-pip.py!! don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seem to be caused by your very slow internet connection. 
If you can't speed it up or change you access point you could download the [matplotlib binaries](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib) and [numpy binaries](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy) and install them offline with `pip install file.whl`

or just try again in a couple of minutes.